# React - Rerender a separate (not child) component

Tags: reactjs

My app displays all books that are provided by a service and I want to have a search bar to search for a specific book.

I have two major components: `NavPanel` and `MainPanel`. `NavPanel` has a child component `SearchBar` and `MainPanel` has a child component `Books`. They are not directly related.

`Books` displays all books and `SearchBar` searches for a specific book.

I have a service called `BooksService` that provides an array of books, and also some methods:

```
export default function BooksService() {
    return {
        reset: function() {
            // resets the array
        }
        getBooks: function() {
            return books; // array
        },
        filterBooks: function(filter) {
            books = books.filter( book => book.author.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()) || book.title.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()));
        }
    }
}
```

When you load the page `Books` component calls `BooksService().getBooks()` to get all the books. When you search for a book in `SearchBar` component, `BooksService().filterBooks(filter)` is called that modifies the array.

Now I would like `Books` to rerender. It would trigger `BooksService().getBooks()` and it would get the modified array. How can I do that?

Comment: why do you set books = books.filter(..) you are changin your original source, that's why next time you call getBooks, it will return the latest filtered array

Comment: I modified the code for the sake of this example. I have an original array stored and it's immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Affect one component from the other, you should use props and here is what you can try

1. Pass books  to Books Component as props.
2. when someone searches, update the books data, hence the books component get render when books data updated.

if you are using Redux, its quite easy to access props and modify prop data,

otherwise store the books data  in Top Container State and pass a function to search component for updating state of top Container with searched books.
And pass same state to books component as prop

Comment: So the component rerenders when props passed to it are changed?

Comment: yes, component renders when either props or state get changed

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass props to the component use a ref (for example `ref="books"`) on the component and do this:

```
this.refs.books.forceUpdate();
```

anyway I suggest using redux for this, keep your books state in a redux reducer and then you can update the books from anywhere in your app.